# Filtering nodes in a DLL

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Here is what I have so far, I want to create the function that would remove elements lower than a specified value in the doubly linked list or above the specified value.

```
class DoublyLinkedList:

    class Node:
        """ Nodes in list """

        def __init__(self, element, prev=None, next_node=None):
            self.element = element
            self.prev = prev
            self.next = next_node

    def __init__(self):
        self._header = self.Node(None, None, None)
        self._trailer = self.Node(None, None, None)
        self._header.next = self._trailer
        self._trailer.prev = self._header
        self._size = 0

    def append(self, element):

        :arg element: the value to add to this list
        
        new_node = self.Node(element, self._trailer.prev, self._trailer)
        self._trailer.prev.next = new_node
        self._trailer.prev = new_node
        self._size += 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size

    def __str__(self):

        # Python's list is used here to avoid string concatenation
        result = []

        current = self._header.next
        for i in range(len(self)):
            result.append(current.element)
            current = current.next

        return str(result)

    def remove(self, low, high):
        for element in self:
            try:
    
            if element.next < low:
                element.next = element.next.next
        
            elif element.next > high:
                element.next = element.next.next
        
            except Exception as e:
                print('low must be less than or equal to high')
        
        pass
```

^^ That is what I've tried so far ^^
here is how I wanted it to work:
I'm not sure how to get it to filter out the higher or lower values

```
DoublyLinkedList.append(5)
DoublyLinkedList.append(7)
DoublyLinkedList.append(8)
DoublyLinkedList.append(3)
DoublyLinkedList.append(9)

[5, 7, 8, 3, 9]


DoublyLinkedList.remove(5,8)

its output should be:

[5, 7, 8]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried something like this so far if element.next.value > high.value:
    element.next = element.next.next

Comment: Could you edit your attempt into the original post?

Comment: Yes ofc, sorry about that

Comment: I wasn't too sure what I was doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues in your code:

- `append` has a line that should be a comment (starting with `#`)
- `for element in self:` will not work, as `self` is not iterable. Also, it is rarely a good idea to iterate over a collection with a `for` loop when you are planning to remove items from that same collection. It will be better to use a form of iteration that you have already used in the `__str__` method.
- `element.next < low` is comparing two different types: `.next` is a node, while `low` is a number. Calling that loop variable `element` is confusing, as that is also the name of the attribute of your nodes. You want to have something like `current.next.element < low`.
- If the above is corrected, there is no reason why the `try` block should trigger an exception, let be that it has to do with how `low` and `high` relate to eachother. If you want to output a message when `high > low`, then don't do that in the loop, but just test for that condition before starting the loop.
- When you remove one node, you should also decrease the list size.
- You can avoid code repetition by using one `if` to compare with `low` and `high` in one expression, using operator chaining
- `DoublyLinkedList` is the class, but a list should be an *instance* of that class. So you need to first create that instance, and then call the methods on that instance, not on the class.

Here is a correction of your code:

```
class DoublyLinkedList:

    class Node:
        """ Nodes in list """

        def __init__(self, element, prev=None, next_node=None):
            self.element = element
            self.prev = prev
            self.next = next_node

    def __init__(self):
        self._header = self.Node(None, None, None)
        self._trailer = self.Node(None, None, None)
        self._header.next = self._trailer
        self._trailer.prev = self._header
        self._size = 0

    def append(self, element):
        # :arg element: the value to add to this list
        new_node = self.Node(element, self._trailer.prev, self._trailer)
        self._trailer.prev.next = new_node
        self._trailer.prev = new_node
        self._size += 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size

    def __str__(self):
        result = []
        current = self._header.next
        for i in range(len(self)):
            result.append(current.element)
            current = current.next
        return str(result)

    def remove(self, low, high):
        # Perform the check before the loop
        if low > high:
            print('low must be less than or equal to high')
            return
        # Iterate the nodes like in __str__, but start one node earlier
        current = self._header
        for i in range(len(self)):
            # Don't compare the node, but its element.
            # Use chained comparison;
            if low <= current.next.element <= high:
                # Only move to next node when not removing
                current = current.next
            else:
                current.next = current.next.next
                self._size -= 1  # Also reduce size

# Should create an instance and work with that
lst = DoublyLinkedList()
lst.append(5)
lst.append(7)
lst.append(8)
lst.append(3)
lst.append(9)
print(lst)  # [5, 7, 8, 3, 9]
lst.remove(5,8)
print(lst)  # [5, 7, 8]
```